# why do i have this error when i am trying to fetch my backend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

when i try to axios.get my backend i receive a network error " err::Network Error "
the code which fails:

```
    axios.get('http://localhost:3001')
    .then((data)=> {
      console.log(data.data.users);
      this.setState({users: data.data.users});
    })
    .catch((err)=>console.log(err));
```

my app.js:

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'users'
});



var app = express();

connection.connect((err)=>{
  (err)? console.log(err+'+++++++++++++++//////////'): console.log('connection********');
});

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{  
    connection.query('select * from informations', (err, data) => {
      (err)?res.send(err):res.json({users: data});
    });
});

app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log(' http://localhost:3001');
 });
```

> i already put proxy: http://localhost:3001 but it still doesnt work

Comment: can you show the actual error with the associated stack trace?

Comment: how do i do it? ^^"

Comment: What do you mean? You copy-paste the actual error into your post, with appropriate markup (either code, or quote, both should work)